GitHub Actions: ERR_PNPM_FETCH_401 Unauthorized - 401 when fetching private npm package from GitHub Packages with pnpm
I’m encountering an ERR_PNPM_FETCH_401 error when trying to install a private npm package from GitHub Packages using GitHub Actions in a monorepo setup. The error message indicates an unauthorized request, despite setting up authentication as described in the documentation. Here’s the error message:
ERR_PNPM_FETCH_401  GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@francislagares/jobber-shared/1.0.5/17a9104c0c7f6c748907155929f68e617e94a62e: Unauthorized - 401
An authorization header was used: ***
These authorization settings were found:
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=NPM_[hidden]

Here is my current github workflow file:
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [22.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup pnpm
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
        with:
          run_install: false

      - name: Get pnpm store directory
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "STORE_PATH=$(pnpm store path | tr -d '\n')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          scope: '@francislagares'

      - name: Setup pnpm cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.STORE_PATH }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-${{ hashFiles('**/pnpm-lock.yaml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pnpm-store-

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: pnpm install
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Generate Prisma ORM schema to the database
        run: pnpm prisma migrate deploy

      - name: Run Tests
        run: pnpm test:ci


Here is my .npmrc file:
@francislagares:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/francislagares
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=NPM_TOKEN

Steps Taken:

Secret Setup: I’ve added the GITHUB_TOKEN as a secret in the repository settings with ALL privileges.
Registry Configuration: Configured the .npmrc file to authenticate with GitHub Packages.
I've tried SO many different configurations and tweaks but still get the same error.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
